# Boolean PHP MySQL Parameter Error

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, I have been working at this for some time. Cannot seem to locate the issue. I have searched through Stackoverflow for similar issues but they all appear to point at the prepare statement for typos.

I haven't found any typos here but I am still getting the error

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, firstname, lastname, date, position, department, manager, birthdate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssss", $param_email, $param_password, $param_firstname, $param_lastname, $param_department, $param_position, $param_manager, $param_date, $param_birthdate);

    $param_email = $email;
    $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $param_firstname = $firstname;
    $param_lastname = $lastname;
    $param_department = $department;
    $param_position = $position;
    $param_manager = $manager;
    $param_date = $date;
    $param_birthdate = $birthdate;

    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        // Redirect to login page
        header("location: index.php");
    } else{
        echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
    }
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: put the last line inside the if

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
  ...
}
```

This is the same as

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
if($stmt){
  ...
}
```

So in your case, the failure on the last line means that the result of `mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)` is a `(boolean) false`. Since you have the last line outside the `if`, it will try to close a `false` instead of a prepared query. Putting it inside the `if` statement, will solve your error, but not why the result is `false`.

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
  ...
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Now for some reason `mysqli_prepare` fails. This can be because of the `$link` or because of the `$sql`. The `$sql` is given and seems to be alright, so the `$link` must be failing.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}


if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
  ...
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 70% of the case, the problem is in your query. The reason why Mysql is giving you an error is because this `($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)` have an error and the `mysqli_prepare` method is returning a `bool`. It should be your query with your `?` as a value. Try replace them with `null`. Tell me if it work.

Comment: No, replacing the '?'s with 'null' did not fix the error

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to check last statement error:

```
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    // Redirect to login page
    header("location: index.php");
} else{
    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Answer (score -1):

variable $stmt is declared to have the type mysqli_stmt within the if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){} statement. declare $stmt before the if-statement or move the last line inside the if-statement.